# How to determine if particular process is running

Tags: vb.net, skype4com

I am building an application to change my Skype status to busy whenever a particular program is being run. I tried the following code:

```
Private Sub WaitTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WaitTimer.Tick
        For Each Me.Process In Process.GetProcesses(My.Computer.Name)
            On Error Resume Next
            If Process.ProcessName = Process.ProcessName = "SCII" Then
                skype.Changeuserstatus(TUserStatus.cusAway)
                Button1.Text = "SCII is running"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        Button1.Text = "SCII is not running"
    End Sub
```

Whenever I run this, it always says SCII is open while it is not. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better more efficient way for checking on running processes other then a timer?

As a side note, I Import Skype4COMLib.

Comment: Does this actually compile?

Comment: yes, it runs perfectly fine but always says that SCII is running.

Comment: I was just wondering what this line supposed to check for `If Process.ProcessName = Process.ProcessName = "SCII" Then` . Was this a typo?

Comment: Oh god, I just realized that... that would be the problem. Not sure how it even ran! Thanks!

Comment: Because the `On Error Resume Next` caught the exception. You should avoid it where you can. `Try catch` blocks can be more explicit about the errors they handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem :

```
If Process.ProcessName = Process.ProcessName = "SCII" Then
```

It should be :

```
If Process.ProcessName = "SCII" Then
```

Comment: I noticed that right after your comment! Such a basic mistake haha!

Comment: Is there a better way to check for the process to be running other then by timer by chance?

Comment: @Nick122 You want to change the status whenever you are using that SCII application? is that an application you developed?

Comment: No, SCII stands for Starcraft 2.

Comment: @Nick122 I think your approach is fine, I'm not entirely sure if you could trigger an event in your application if another application runs.

Comment: One thing I noticed briefly is that the memory it consumes slowly goes up every 5 seconds(The timer tick). Any chance this would eventually take up a large amount of memory? Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @Nick122 In my opinion, 5 seconds tick is too short. Why not change it to 1 minute at least? For what it's worth, you could monitor the application without a timer if you launch the SCII from within your application, [check this out](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/Process.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

THe issue is `On Error Resume Next`. This is resuming inside the if statment. As the comparison `(Process.ProcessName = Process.ProcessName) = "SCII"` always throws an exception you always resume inside the if on the first loop.

Consider removing `On Error Resume Next` if you do not expect an error or replacing it with a `try catch` block if you do.

Answer (score 0):

This tells you in a message box if a process is found from all the running processes. If the process is running it will be displayed in a few seconds or so.

```
Sub CheckIfRunning()
    Dim pList() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    For Each proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In pList
        If proc.ProcessName.ToString = "App".ToString Then
              MsgBox(proc.ProcessName.ToString & " Found")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```